# Merging two excel files in c# without using interop

Tags: c#, excel

I have to merge two excel files containing one sheet in each of them and I have to generate a third file containing two sheets corresponding to the two original sheets.

This task can be done using "interop" and the code works but when the same code is run in a system that does not contain MS Office, the process fails and an error comes up.

Can you please guide me as to what dll files to be included or how this merging could be done without using interop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you searched for such type of solution in Open XML?

Comment: Try ClosedXml http://closedxml.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

From what I've experienced, there is unfortunately no framework way of doing this (without writing your own excel file reader).  I happened across this interesting library which does just that.

http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

So far it has worked for our needs and requires no interop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an external component to work with excel files. I use the [syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/) xslIo.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have raw data (no formulas, etc) you could also just save the files using the XML Spreadsheet 2003 (*.xml) format (its very easy to read) and process the data using standard XML tools.